# Using Devise with Paypal for User Creation and Subscription Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to extend the Devise user/sign_up path to include subscription payment. My aim is to have a user create their account only after payment has been processed.

For the authentication I am using Devise, for payment I am using AM and Paypal API. The closest thing I have found is: http://rorramblings.blogspot.com/2010/10/customizing-devise-to-pseudo-multi.html yet it seems to be missing quite a bit of the details. A push in the right direction will help!

As far as recurring Paypal Payments, I have found the following: http://www.naivehack.com/2010/11/24/active-merchant-paypal-recurring-payment/  [http://www.parkerkohl.com/paypal-rails-3-recurring-billing/] ... hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after the user pays on paypal, paypal sends the user to the return url back on your site. Have the return url point to a page where the user can sign up.

Comment: thank you for your input, I appreciate it greatly. What would stop a user from finding the 'return url point page' any bypassing the subscription system?

Comment: well put that code in your process url which would be the return url and then in the profile_response.success? then redirect to the user sign up page, make sure to save all of the subscription info first including the profile_response.params["profile_id"] then pass the same id into the user sign up, then in the user sign up require and check to see if the profile id is in the database. If its missing or not valid then redirect to some place else.

Comment: Mike, I've been going at it implementing your strategy and have hit the wall in one area... I have the paypal button and checkout coded and a controller/model capturing the paypal IPN transaction_id and profile_id (along with the other params). The only thing I am unsure of is how to pass the transaction_id value from my IPN controller/model(db) to the User controller/view so that when the user hits the user creation page the transaction_id value is present. Thoughts?

Comment: in your ipn controller add a session variable session[:trans_id] = 'user trans id'. Then in your user controller call the session variable, @user.trans_id = session[:trans_id]